# Lists in pgu and python

Tags: python, pgu

I'm searching for help about lists in pgu gui for python. I need to know which methods and properties they have, so I can include them in my programs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, pyfunc. I do have the examples analyzed, but when I do import pgu.gui.List, i get: No module named pgu.gui.List

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion

**Use python's builtins to introspect on**

```
import pgu.gui.List
import inspect
help(pgu.gui.List) # to read out the doc strings
print dir(pgu.gui.List) # to get the namespace of List class
# to get all methods of that class
all_functions = inspect.getmembers(pgu.gui.List, inspect.isfunction)
```

**Always look at the source code, when it is available**

- http://code.google.com/p/pgu/source/browse/trunk/pgu/gui/area.py

**From the code: You can create and clear a list.**

```
class List(ScrollArea):
    """A list of items in an area.

    <p>This widget can be a form element, it has a value set to whatever item is selected.</p>

    <pre>List(width,height)</pre>
    """
    ....
    def clear(self):
        """Clear the list.

        <pre>List.clear()</pre>
        """
        ...
```

**Usage :**

```
# Create the actual widget
    usagelist = gui.List(width, height)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, pyfunc. I do have the examples analyzed, but when I do import pgu.gui.List, i get: No module named pgu.gui.List